# compiling android source code under max os X(10.9)

Tags: android

I'm currently running Mac OS X(10.9),and a few issue with compiling android source code.
I download android source code fine in case sensitive disk(/Volume/android),follow this 
site http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html and make version 3.81.
Below is part of my ~/.bash_profile

```
    ===================================================================================================
function mountAndroid { hdiutil attach ~/android.dmg.sparseimage -mountpoint /Volumes/android; }
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# set the number of open files to be 1024
ulimit -S -n 1024
PATH=~/bin:$PATH

##
# Your previous /Users/chousodaera/.bash_profile file was backed up as /Users/chousodaera/.bash_profile.macports-saved_2013-11-01_at_12:37:13
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2013-11-01_at_12:37:13: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
 export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
===================================================================================================
```

but i still compile android source code fail.
does anyone have any ideas help me to fix this problem?
Bellow is my error message.

```
choumato-MacBook-Pro:android chousodaera$ make
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=4.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=full
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a
HOST_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=ITL41D
============================================

host C: acp <= build/tools/acp/acp.c
build/tools/acp/acp.c:11:10: fatal error: 'stdlib.h' file not found
#include <stdlib.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [out/host/darwin-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you haven't set up the build environment correctly in Mac OS. Install Xcode from the Apple developer site along with the command line utils. Also Make sure that /opt/local/bin appears in your path before /usr/bin.

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

Use this as a refrence for setting up the build environment: https://source.android.com/source/initializing.html